# Hide time by MD5 or similar in PHP file

Tags: php, md5, strtotime

My client want to give a user access to a certain page only for a couple of days. After that the client has to contact him again. For this I created the following code.

```
<head>
<style>
body {height: 100%;width: 100%;overflow: hidden;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
iframe {border: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$expireDate = strtotime("2013-12-01");
if ($today < $expireDate) {
echo "<iframe src='http://www.domain.eu/active'>";
} else {
echo "<iframe src='http://www.domain.eu/deactive'>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically when the time of today is less than the date in `$expireDate = strtotime("2013-12-01");` it shows the deactive page. But the code above is located into an index.php file that the client has to upload to its server. Now when the client is a little bit smart he/she can change the date to whatever they want and have access all the time. How can I make this part `$expireDate = strtotime("2013-12-01");` use MD5 or something similar.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: So you want your client to have access to the code AND protect the same code from misuse? Forget it. Security through obfuscation is always a result of bad design and bad design will result. Either give the client complete access or take the code in a secure location.

Comment: You appear to be applying this protection in the wrong place — the user can bypass all of this by going straight to `http://www.domain.eu/active`.

Comment: @Saturnix I agree with your statements. And therefore discontinued the above stated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide/encode/encrypt php source code and let others have the system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203112/is-it-possible-to-hide-encode-encrypt-php-source-code-and-let-others-have-the-sy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should solve this primary in PHP (within the iframe):

```
<?php
  if( $today >= $expireDate ) 
  {
    include_once 'inactive.php';
  }
  else 
  {
    include_once 'active.php';
  }
?>
```

**Another solution:**

Or you can use base64_encode() to hash your timestamp instead of using md5.

Comment: "But the code above is located into an index.php file that the client has to upload to its server". Hence, this won't solve anything. I could take your if statement, delete it and reupload the page to the server. We're not talking about PHP running in a secure server but about PHP code which can be seen by the same person from which it should be protected.

Comment: Oh, that's fine for him :) Then only way is to obsfucate your code someway. You can use PHP openssl_encrypt / openssl_decrypt. But the person can still modify your code. I'd still recommend server-request within the iframe as I've answered above.

Answer (score 0):

You are using iframes. What is keeping the client from just accessing the URL directly?

Assuming that you have control over the website that is included in the iframe:

Give each client an access key. Store that access key in your DB with an expiry date. Make it so that the URL he is accessing needs the access key (GET parameter for example), otherwise redirect to your other page.

If you don't have control over the site, upload a script on a server which does nothing else than doing the access control as described above and then returns the content from the real URL.

Either way, to make things secure you need to have the request going through a script/server that you are in control of.