# PHP source code protection method?

Tags: php

I'm using php mysql for system development.

My problem is when we are giving source code at the end of development **is there a way to encode source code** (So your code is unreadable)

something like compiling in java???

Comment: Check something about "compiling in java" http://stackoverflow.com/a/272595/251311

Comment: No. PHP is more a scripting language which is interpreted. No way to protect the source code if someone else should work with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203112/is-it-possible-to-hide-encode-encrypt-php-source-code-and-let-others-have-the-sy

Comment: if they want to just run the script on their local machine for testing purpose you must see this "obfuscate php" http://www.phpencode.org/ many similar sites available. BUT it is reversible.

Comment: "obfuscate php"  seems to be positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some commercial solutions available like [ioncube's php encoder](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php), [zend guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/), and [phpshield](http://www.phpshield.com/) that will all do what you're asking. Hope this helps :)