# How to hide a web code source in the server

Tags: php, obfuscation

Recently I developed a web application and I will publish it in the web by giving the code source to company which will do the necessary. All of I want is to know if there is any possibility to give them the application but without a source code, like an encrypted source code or some thing in this way. The application runs with Apache and phpmyadmin, and I don't want to make any confusing with them. Thanks a lot for you.

Comment: Check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203112/is-it-possible-to-hide-encode-encrypt-php-source-code-and-let-others-have-the-sy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203112/is-it-possible-to-hide-encode-encrypt-php-source-code-and-let-others-have-the-sy)

Comment: ^ a.k.a possible duplicate of ...

Comment: The best way to hide the source is to wrap it in a layer of lawyers and contracts

Comment: ... or rewrite it in C as an Apache extension and supply only the compiled binary... good luck with that though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you, your response really help me and it is what i was searching for, thank you. And sorry for the duplication

Comment: The correct answer to this question is **no**. You can try to hide your source code all you want through obfuscation or encryption, but you will not stop anyone that really wants to reverse engineer your software. The ones you do manage to stop with these petty tools mentioned in the duplicate answer are not the ones you're worried about stealing your software anyway. So you've accomplished nothing by using these tools. The better solution is not give out your source code and instead sell your software as [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any php code obfuscator or php code encoder 
http://www.ioncube.com/ is a good code encoder and used by whmcs. And there are many free obfuscators

Obfuscation is making the source code difficult to understand for humans by changing the source code. It sometimes reduces size too. Encoders represent the code in another form which is difficult for humans.